# Javascript - Time and space complexity of splice and concat inside loop

Tags: javascript, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory, space-complexity

I have a problem which requires a string to be transformed into another one by appending copies of its' initial value to itself. The problem allows to remove single characters at some places.

Explanation

```
let x = "abba"; // First string
let y = "aba" // Second initial string

y("aba") => remove last "a" => y("ab") => y+initialY = "ab"+"aba" => 
y("ababa") => remove char at index 2 => y("abba") => y == x => sucess
```

My algorithm successfully solves the problem:

```
let x = "abbbbcccaaac"
let y = "abc"

let xArr = x.split('')
let yArr = y.split('')

let count = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < xArr.length; i++) {
  if(yArr[i] == undefined) {
    yArr = yArr.concat(y.split(''));  
    count++;
  }
  if(xArr[i] != yArr[i]) {
    yArr.splice(i, 1);
    i--;
  }
}

console.log("Output is:", yArr.join(''))
console.log("Appends in order to transform:", count)
```

The algorithm works as intended, however, I am uncertain regarding its time and space complexity and most importantly - efficiency.

1. Is this algorithm in `O(n)` time complexity where n is the length of `x`?
2. If this is not `O(n)`, can the problem be solved in `O(n)` time?
3. Does `.concat()`, `.splice()` or `.split()` somehow change the time complexity since they are nested in a for loop? What if they weren't, do they still change the time complexity of an algorithm and by how much?
4. Given the rules of this problem, is this an efficient way to solve it?
5. What is the space complexity of this algorithm?

Comment: Actually, if we really knew the time-complexity of splice, split or concat, then it would obviously affect the overall time-complexity of your algorithm. But since we don't, we would regard them as a constant operation, O(1), which in effect keeps the loop operation at an O(N) - worst case.  The space complexity is O(1) because we are not creating new storage (in this case, count) for every loop operation rather we just update it. IMO, it's a fair solution since I don't know what the constraints for your given problem are.

Comment: @CalebLucas "But since we don't, we would regard them as a constant operation" - should we? Would this problem still be meaningful in that case? Besides, the ECMA specification provides hints as to what they are.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog "should we?" - I feel it depends on one's objective. These functions are optimized at runtime by the javascript engine. If the aim is to really dig into the specifics of each function and their application in a given scenario, then sure, considering their time-complexity would be paramount.

Comment: @CalebLucas you are right split() ,concat() etc have been optimize by JS engine. However that doesn't mean there is no time/space complexity for those operation. There are 2 answer to this based on intention of the question. If this is for interview then we need consider time and space complexity of those methods. If it's for app you don't need to worry about. Looking at question, it seems interview question, for that OP need to consider those thing because next question will be with is complexity for this algo

Answer (score 3):

Normally a question like this is quite difficult to give a definite answer to, because different implementations of Javascript have different time complexities for basic array operations (such as [creating a new array of size n](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59755757/12299000)). Javascript arrays will typically be implemented either as [dynamic arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array) or [hashtables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashtable), and these data structures have different performance characteristics.

So, there is no definitive time complexity for `splice` to remove one element from an array. What we can say is that removing one element takes linear time for a dynamic array, and as @Ry- points out in the comments, also linear time for a hashtable, because of the need to renumber the later indices. We can also say that it's highly likely one of these two data structures is used, and no sensible implementation will take *more* than linear time to do `splice`.

Either way, the worst case for your algorithm is when `x = 'aa...aa'` and `y = 'abb...bb'`, i.e. `x` is n copies of `'a'`, and `y` is `'a'` followed by (m - 1) copies of `'b'`.

For a dynamic array *or* a hashtable, then the time complexity for just the `splice` operations is O(nm²). This is because the outer loop iterates O(nm) times (note the `i--` inside the loop, which happens every time the letter `'b'` needs to be removed), and the `splice` operation requires shifting or renumbering O(m) elements in `yArr` after index `i`.

But suppose some more exotic data structure is used which supports removing an element in sub-linear time (e.g. a [skip list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list)). In that case, the above only gives O(nm) times the complexity of the "remove" operation. But we haven't counted `concat` yet; this creates a new data structure and copies every item into it, which will still take linear time. `concat` is called O(n) times and takes an average of O(n + m) time per call, so the complexity of just the `concat` operations is O(n² + nm).

So the time complexity is very likely O(n² + nm²), and certainly at least O(n² + nm); not linear.

---

The space complexity is O(n), since the length of `yArr` is never more than twice as long as `xArr`.

Comment: `splice(i, 1)` isn’t O(1) for an index -> value hashtable, because it has to renumber everything.